Connection timeout to redis docker image from spring boot app when using VPN
I have a spring boot app thats running NOT in docker. For local test runs, I have a docker-compose.yml to start required tools:
services:
  redis:
    image: hub.server.lan/redis:5.0.14
    ports:
        - "6379:6379"
    environment:
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes

  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"

  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: 127.0.0.1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: 'true'
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: 'local-topic'

docker is running under the ip I defined in the docker daemon.json:
9: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:8a:e7:84:4f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 213.240.0.1/24 brd 213.240.0.255 scope global docker0

The app connects to the kafka instance with localhost:9092 without a problem.
The app can however NOT connect to the redis instance with localhost:6379, only when I explicitly connect to 213.240.0.1:6379.
A locally installed another-redis-desktop-manager instance can connect to the redis using localhost:6379 without any problem.
I am getting a ConnectionTimeoutException:
Caused by: io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out after 10000 ms: localhost.company.domain/10.20.59.212:6379
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe$2.run(AbstractEpollChannel.java:615)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask.runTask(PromiseTask.java:98)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledFutureTask.java:153)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:173)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:166)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:469)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:408)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:994)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)

My resolv.conf:
#@VPNC_GENERATED@ -- this file is generated by vpnc
# and will be overwritten by vpnc
# as long as the above mark is intact
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 172.19.254.1
nameserver 172.19.255.1
search fritz.box company.domain

When not using VPN, connection works with localhost:6379, so it is not a configuration issue in the .yml files or in code (I suppose).
EDIT: I can get it to work when changing the searh in the resolv.conf to
search localhost fritz.box company.domain

But I have no clue why that works
